# Error while trying to access my pgadmin 4 database using spring-boot maven and REST API in java

Tags: spring-boot, rest, maven, spring-data-jpa, pgadmin-4

I am currently just trying to set up a database in pgadmin and access it in spring-boot. I set up a schema called "stuffed_animals", inside a table called "pets" with a bunch of columns. I have a controller, service, repository for the "pet" model and I'm using the JpaRepository.

What I am trying to do is have a findAll() function that will return all the data I have in the "pets" table. But when trying to go to "localhost:9000/pets" I receive the following error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt8qp.png)

The full length error there that is cut out:

2023-04-06T12:08:09.691+03:00 ERROR 3220 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select p1_0.id,p1_0.age,p1_0.animal,p1_0.birthdate,p1_0.food,p1_0.hobby,p1_0.name,p1_0.owner from pets p1_0]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

I will include the code for the Application.java, Controller, Repository, Service and Model, aswell as the pom.xml and application.properties file. Also an image of the hierarchy in the pgadmin and intellij.

I suspect the issue is in either in the pom.xml or application.properties

Thanks in advance!

Application.java:

```
package StuffedAnimals;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

PetController.java:

```
import StuffedAnimals.Services.PetService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@CrossOrigin
public class PetController {

    @Autowired
    private PetService petService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/pets")
    public List<Pet> getAll() {
        return this.petService.getAll();
    }

}
```

PetService.java:

```
package StuffedAnimals.Services;

import StuffedAnimals.Models.Pet;
import StuffedAnimals.Repositories.PetRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PetService {

    @Autowired
    private PetRepository petRepository;

    public List<Pet> getAll() {
        return this.petRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

PetRepository.java:

```
package StuffedAnimals.Repositories;

import StuffedAnimals.Models.Pet;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Integer> {
}
```

Pet.java:

```
package StuffedAnimals.Models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pets")
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "owner")
    private String owner;

    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    private Date birthdate;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "animal")
    private String animal;

    @Column(name = "food")
    private String food;

    @Column(name = "hobby")
    private String hobby;

    public Pet() {}

    public Pet(String name, String owner, Date birthdate, int age, String animal, String food, String hobby) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setOwner(owner);
        this.setBirthdate(birthdate);
        this.setAge(age);
        this.setAnimal(animal);
        this.setFood(food);
        this.setHobby(hobby);
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setAnimal(String animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public void setHobby(String hobby) {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }

    public Date getBirthdate() {
        return this.birthdate;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public String getAnimal() {
        return this.animal;
    }

    public String getFood() {
        return this.food;
    }

    public String getHobby() {
        return this.hobby;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id: " + this.getId()
                + "\nName: " + this.getName()
                + "\nOwner: " + this.getOwner()
                + "\nBirthdate: " + this.getBirthdate()
                + "\nAge: " + this.getAge()
                + "\nAnimal: " + this.getAnimal()
                + "\nFood: " + this.getFood()
                + "\nHobby: " + this.getHobby();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(other instanceof Pet otherPet)) {
            return false;
        }

        return this.getName().equals(otherPet.getName())
                && this.getOwner().equals(otherPet.getOwner())
                && this.getBirthdate().equals(otherPet.getBirthdate())
                && this.getAge() == otherPet.getAge()
                && this.getAnimal().equals(otherPet.getAnimal())
                && this.getFood().equals(otherPet.getFood())
                && this.getHobby().equals(otherPet.getHobby());
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>StuffedAnimals</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Bring my stuffed animals to the WEB!</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.schema=stuffed_animals

server.port=9000
```

[Hierarchy in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP8hk.png)

[Hierarchy in PgAdmin 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrpnO.png)

Comment: There are no getters and setters in the entity class. Hint: use Lombok plugin for this

Comment: @Mar-Z I added them but still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL error seen on the screenshot says 'relation "pets" does not exist'. On another screenshot can be seen that the table 'pets' does exist but in a specific schema 'stuffed_animals'. It means that JPA is using a default (none) schema for access. You meant to define the schema as a property but unfortunately using a wrong one. The correct setting would be:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema  = stuffed_animals
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had to add this and also change the annotation in the Controller from "@Controller" to "@RestController"